# How do i capture the HID input using Python and Linux?

Tags: python, linux, linux-kernel, python-2.7, linux-device-driver

I have IPD Ultima joystick connected to my Linux box. When i do following:

$ modprobe uinput
$ lsmod | grep uinput

```
uinput                 17246  0
```

$ lsusb - ok

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0461:4d65 Primax Electronics, Ltd
```

$ xinput list - nothing at all

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Optical Mouse                         id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

$ dmesg - ok

```
H PRODUCTS CH Products IPD Ultima] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
[42731.000208] usb 3-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[42737.291095] usb 3-1: new low-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[42737.457157] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=068e, idProduct=0060
[42737.457167] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[42737.457175] usb 3-1: Product: CH Products IPD Ultima
[42737.457182] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: CH PRODUCTS
[42737.489359] input: CH PRODUCTS CH Products IPD Ultima as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.1/usb3/3-1/3-1:1.0/input/input13
[42737.489867] generic-usb 0003:068E:0060.0005: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Joystick [CH PRODUCTS CH Products IPD Ultima] on usb-0000:00:1d.1-1/input0
```

$ python it: - not ok

```
sf1 = open("test.usbdump").read() # read the earlier usb dump from hiddevice
kb = open("/dev/usb/hiddev0")
while 1:
  print (kb.read(len(sf1)) == sf1)
```

$ pgame it: - not ok

```
#/usr/bin/env python
#
# yum list installed pygame*
#Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
#Installed Packages
#pygame.i686                               1.9.1-6.fc15                          @updates
#pygame-devel.i686                         1.9.1-6.fc15                          @updates

import os, pygame
from pygame.locals import *
def main():
  pygame.init()
  pygame.joystick.init()
  pygame.display.set_mode((468, 60))
  pygame.display.set_caption('HID Python')
  pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)

  while 1:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      print event.type
      if event.type == QUIT:
        return
      elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
        return
      elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print '\/'
      elif event.type is MOUSEBUTTONUP:
        print '/\'
      elif event.type is JOYAXISMOTION:
        print '()'
      elif event.type is JOYBALLMOTION:
        print '()()'
      elif event.type is JOYHATMOTION:
        print '<>'
      elif event.type is JOYBUTTONUP:
        print '//\\'
      elif event.type is JOYBUTTONDOWN:
        print '\\//'

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  main()
```

No luck. Any help idea why i can not get anything ?

**Follow up:**

```
# cat /dev/input/js0 
=c��=c��=c��=c��=c��=c��=c��=c��=c�=c�� =c��
=c��
     =c��=c��=c��
&n��n�Vp�&q�r��r�Nt��t�>u��u��v�w�~w��z���{��|�}�n}��}�~�N~��~��~�.������������������������>�����拋6�����V�����������6�����&��������v��昋�v��
```

Comment: Have you tried the event subsystem yet?

Comment: @lgnacio Vazquez-Abrams: I have not tried something like this, as i do not know how to do it yet. Is this similar to like this you mean? e.g: http://mkeys.sourceforge.net/input_setup.html

Comment: You don't need to make the nodes yourself on modern systems, but that is the subsystem I mean.

Comment: How can i decode this inputs from the event triggers which is found now in js0.

Comment: you may want to have a look at here : [Interrogating linux /dev/usb/hiddev0 in python (Python recipe)](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576834/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a decoder from the capture inputs.